# Toast message position doesnt change

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I want to show toast message top of page.When ı run these codes ,toast message show bottom of page.I watched some totarials.They used similar codes and it is work(They have only one layout this totarials).Is problem about my layout or Activity ?Is there another way to change of toast message position ? or What should ı change in my code?

Activity Code :

```
package com.example.challenge_1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /*************************
     *Variable Deaclare
     * */


    Button btnTrue,btnFalse,btnNext;
    TextView textToast;

    Toast toastTrue,toastFalse,toast;

    View layout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /*********************
         * Button Assigin*
         * ****************/

        btnFalse=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_false);
        btnTrue=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_true);
        btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


        /****************
         * Toast message assign
         */

        //Toast Messages Possion
        toastFalse=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,R.string.btnIs_False,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toastFalse.setGravity(Gravity.TOP ,0,0);

        toastTrue=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,R.string.btnIs_True,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toastTrue.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);




        btnFalse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                toastFalse.show();

            }
        });
        btnTrue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toastTrue.show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textView_Canberra"
            android:textAlignment="center"
             />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btnIs_True">
            </Button>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btnIs_False">
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_next"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btn_next">
            </Button>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BTN);



 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                      
  

 Toast t1=Toast.makeText(this,"Toast.GRAVITY.TOP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                 t1.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);
                 t1.show();
   


 Toast   t2=Toast.makeText(this,"Toast.GRAVITY.CENTER",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                     t2.setGravity(Gravity.TOP,0,0);
                     t2.show();
    
         



 }
            });
```

Comment: But i have copied from my working project!May be write about which version of Android studio u r using and your minimum SDK target

Comment: Android studio 4.0.1,  minSdkVersion 15

Answer (score 0):

You should note that your whole primary layout has gravity set to center which overrides the Toast's placement preference. It is also good practice to set properties just before show. So, change the property followed by `.show();`
In fact, why don't you just shorten all that code to 2 lines, 1 for each case:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0).show();
```

Declare Toast only when you need it. It should not be class-wide variable. Because you haven't created an instance of it at that scale. It's null on declaration.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 0, 0).show();` when ı use it ı get this error "Cannot resolve method 'show() "                         
  I tried ur layout advice.I was thinking same as you but it didint work